# library to generate Multi tags from text data?

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger

I want to generate MultiTag from any text file. Suppose i have subtitles from one of the video from Machine Learning Course.

> *"In the last video, we talked about the hypothesis representation for logistic regression. What Id like to do now is tell you about something called the decision boundary, and this will give us a better sense of what the logistic regressions hypothesis function is computing. 
>   To recap, this is what we wrote out last time, where we said that the hypothesis is represented as h of x equals g of theta transpose x, where g is this function called the sigmoid function, which looks like this. It slowly increases from zero to one, asymptoting at one".*

from above text i want to generate tag like : **Hypothesis Representation ,logistic regression, decision boundary,sigmoid function**

Any Tagger is based on two model *Supervised and Unsupervised*.Since these text can belong to any domain, not just technical domain, therefore i do not have proper training set to train my model based on Supervised Learning so i choose Unsupervised techniques.

I tried different python library to generate tag, but did not succeed. I used below library:

> Nltk library, spacy, textBlob,rake,ngram meathod.

i wrote my own methods to solve this but i am able to generate single tag only. I used Brown nltk corpus to calculate weight for every words in the text and based on the weight i sorted the list of words. But it is not accurate though. Below is the code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from nltk.corpus import brown
import operator
from _io import open
news_text = brown.words()
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in news_text)

def subtitle_to_words( subtitles ):

    #  Remove HTML
    review_text = BeautifulSoup(subtitles, "lxml").get_text() 

    #  Remove non-letters        
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", review_text) 
    #
    # 3. Convert to lower case, split into individual words
    words = letters_only.lower().split()                             
    #
    #  convert the stop words to a set
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))                  
    # 
    # 5. Remove stop words
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]   
    #
    # 6. Join the words back into one string separated by space, 
    # and return the result.
    return( meaningful_words) 


text=open('text4.txt','r')
withoutStopWords=subtitle_to_words(text)
keyword_dict={}
abs_occurences_dict={}
for m in withoutStopWords:
    if m not in abs_occurences_dict.keys():
        abs_occurences_dict[m]=1
    else:
        abs_occurences_dict[m]+=1
    keyword_dict[m]=abs_occurences_dict[m]/float((fdist[m.lower()]+1))

sorted_dict = sorted(keyword_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
for i in range(0,int(len(sorted_dict))):
    if len(sorted_dict[i][0])>2:
        print(sorted_dict[i][0])
```

Can anyone suggest any method or Python library to solve this problem.

Comment: interesting question - please share the code you tried and what accuracies you achieved

Comment: @miraculixx just added the code, this one is not  close to solution but i am still trying out.